# how to get dynamically generated http request values jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am recording https request using jmeter. My application generates a three random values while recording a steps.
while playing the recorded steps same values are going in request. how to get dynamically generated values?

Comment: You need to use the Regular expression extractor post processor. First, extract the dynamic values from the response and then pass it to the next sampler

Answer (score 2):

The process of handling dynamic values is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), you should be handling it as follows:

1. Add a [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as a child of the request which returns dynamic value. The most commonly used is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), however depending on your response data format you might want to use others like:

   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - for HTML
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - for HTML, XHTML and XML
   - [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) - for JSON

   Given your expression is correct and it matches the dynamic value, the value will be stored as a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Use the JMeter Variable created in step 1 where required.

N.B. JMeter Variables scope is limited to current [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) only